# How to pinpoint systemout of memory issue for a .Net web application in windows 2003 server (32 bit)

Tags: performance, testing, memory

We did a performance test on a .Net web application running on Windows 2003 server. The application crashed with system out of memory exception. We noticed that when the virtual byte hit 1.8 GB, the application crashed. However, the memory available bytes were above 2.5 GB at all time. There is no configuration found that limit the memory usage for the process.
Any suggestions on how to pinpoint the cause the issue? Could any one help me understand why there is still so many memory available but the application crashes with system out of memory exception?

Answer (score 0):

What is the .net version?
Is the windows server 32bit or 64bit?

If you have a 32bit Windows, then you can follow this guide to investigate the leak:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/01/14/debugging-native-memory-leaks-with-debug-diag-1-1.aspx

If you have 64bit Windows, then let me know. I will explain a longer, more difficult approach.

Comment: The server is Widnows 2003 32bits. .Net version is 3.5
Thank you for providing the link. It is helpful.